# Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException BitmapFactory

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have a file where permissions are defined. The code works for lower versions of android but 8.0 and higher don't. So I explicitly requested with a self-permission check. This code was working yesterday, but suddenly I again get the same permission denied error.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    //    Activity#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

Comment: go to setting , apps, check the permission of your app because you are not asking for permission just checking it

Comment: Is the file present in Internal storage or SD card?

Comment: You were right. Thanks. How can I enable it as the app starts ? I have defined it in my androidmanifest.xml too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request permission and if permission is not granted then show a placeholder image or an error.

From https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Permission is not granted
    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
    } else {
        // No explanation needed; request the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
        // If the callback is successful, show image, otherwise error
    }
} else {
    // Permission has already been granted SHOW IMAGE
}
```